# Remove all occurrences except last?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all occurrences of substring = `.` in a string except the last one.

E.G:

```
1.2.3.4
```

should become:

```
123.4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

2-liner:

```
function removeAllButLast(string, token) {
    /* Requires STRING not contain TOKEN */
    var parts = string.split(token);
    return parts.slice(0,-1).join('') + token + parts.slice(-1)
}
```

Alternative version without the requirement on the string argument:

```
function removeAllButLast(string, token) {
    var parts = string.split(token);
    if (parts[1]===undefined)
        return string;
    else
        return parts.slice(0,-1).join('') + token + parts.slice(-1)
}
```

Demo:

```
> removeAllButLast('a.b.c.d', '.')
"abc.d"
```

The following one-liner is a regular expression that takes advantage of the fact that the `*` character is greedy, and that replace will leave the string alone if no match is found. It works by matching [longest string including dots][dot] and leaving [rest of string], and if a match is found it strips all '.'s from it:

```
'a.b.c.d'.replace(/(.*)\./, x => x.replace(/\./g,'')+'.')
```

(If your string contains newlines, you will have to use `[.\n]` rather than naked `.`s)

Comment: just for info: if someone needs to remove all but first then use  >>>  function removeAllButFirst(string, token) {
    
    var parts = string.split(token);
    
    return  parts.slice(0,1) + token + parts.slice(1).join('');
}

Comment: additional info, if the string does not contain the token, it will get added.

Comment: @Ello: thanks for finding that, added fix and also a regex method.

Answer (score 50):

You can use regex with positive look ahead,

```
"1.2.3.4".replace(/[.](?=.*[.])/g, "");
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To say this in English, the regex says "match all occurrences of . that have another . after them", then you simply replace with an empty string. You'll hear occasional complaints that regex aren't as readable as doing a big split then formatting from the array, but it's pretty easy to simply describe your regex in a comment above it.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to put too much stock in isolated performance tests that the engine won't be as smart about optimising, but the positive lookahead doesn't seem to scale as nicely. Here I found it's quite a bit faster for short strings (the '1.2.3.4' example) vs splitting the array, but lags way behind on longer strings: https://jsperf.com/removing-all-but-last-string-token

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
var str = '1.2.3.4';
var last = str.lastIndexOf('.');
var butLast = str.substring(0, last).replace(/\./g, '');
var res = butLast + str.substring(last);
```

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/qwjaW/

Answer (score 7):

You could take a positive lookahead (for keeping the last dot, if any) and replace the first coming dots.

```js
var string = '1.2.3.4';

console.log(string.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

A `replaceAllButLast` function is more useful than a `removeAllButLast` function. When you want to remove just replace with an empty string:

```js
function replaceAllButLast(str, pOld, pNew) {
  var parts = str.split(pOld)
  if (parts.length === 1) return str
  return parts.slice(0, -1).join(pNew) + pOld + parts.slice(-1)
}

var test = 'hello there hello there hello there'
test = replaceAllButLast(test, ' there', '')

console.log(test) // hello hello hello there
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a much better way of doing this. Here is `replaceAllButLast` and `appendAllButLast` as they should be done. The latter does a replace whilst preserving the original match. To remove, just replace with an empty string.

```js
var str = "hello there hello there hello there"

function replaceAllButLast(str, regex, replace) {
  var reg = new RegExp(regex, 'g')
  return str.replace(reg, function(match, offset, str) {
      var follow = str.slice(offset);
      var isLast = follow.match(reg).length == 1;
      return (isLast) ? match : replace
  })
}

function appendAllButLast(str, regex, append) {
  var reg = new RegExp(regex, 'g')
  return str.replace(reg, function(match, offset, str) {
      var follow = str.slice(offset);
      var isLast = follow.match(reg).length == 1;
      return (isLast) ? match : match + append
  })
}

var replaced = replaceAllButLast(str, / there/, ' world')
console.log(replaced)

var appended = appendAllButLast(str, / there/, ' fred')
console.log(appended)
```

Thanks to @leaf for these masterpieces which he gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992112/javascript-replace-all-but-last-whilst-preserving-original-line-breaks).

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the string, remove all occurrences of substring except the first, and reverse it again to get what you want.

Comment: What makes you think removing all occurences except the first is any easier then the other way around?

Comment: looping through the string, its easier to maintain a flag to know that the first has passed, and we can proceed to remove all the occurrences now. Easier and more readable than reverse looping through the string using str.charAt method. You can always remember the location of last occurrence using str.lastIndexOf, but that location will keep changing as you remove any substrings occurring earlier, so it needs to be recalculated.

Comment: A backwards loop is better then two calls to reverse

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatString() {
  var arr = ('1.2.3.4').split('.');
  var arrLen = arr.length-1;
  var outputString = '.' + arr[arrLen];
  for (var i=arr.length-2; i >= 0; i--) {
     outputString = arr[i]+outputString;
  }
  alert(outputString);
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/izebay

Answer (score 0):

**var s='1.2.3.4';**

```
s=s.split('.');
s.splice(s.length-1,0,'.');
s.join('');
```

**123.4**