# Remove specific words except last in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a sentence that I would like to have only the last 'and' remaining, and remove the others.

"Lions, and tigers, and bears, and elephants", and I would like to turn this into:

"Lions, tigers, bears, and elephants".

I have tried using a regex pattern like `str = str.replace(/and([^and]*)$/, '$1');` which obviously didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: `split` at the word you want, `join` with empty in all instances except the last.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694930/remove-all-occurrences-except-last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/RYipEx/2):

```
and (?=.*and)
```

- `and` matches any and followed by a space. Space is matched so it is removed on replacement, to prevent having 2 spaces
- `(?=.*and)` is a lookahead, meaning it will only match if followed by `.*and`, if followed by and

Use this code:

```
str = str.replace(/and (?=.*and)/g, '');
```

Comment: perfect! although I went with this `str = str.replace( /\and (?=.*and)/g, '');` thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. You need to use a regex literal and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive look-ahead `(?=...)`, to see if there is another `and` ahead of the current match. You also need to make the regex global with `g`.

```js
function removeAllButLastAnd(str) {
  return str.replace(/and\s?(?=.*and)/g, '');
}

console.log(removeAllButLastAnd("Lions, and tigers, and bears, and elephants"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var multipleAnd = "Lions, and tigers, and bears, and elephants";
var lastAndIndex = multipleAnd.lastIndexOf(' and');
var onlyLastAnd = multipleAnd.substring(0, lastAndIndex).replace(/ and/gi, '')+multipleAnd.substring(lastAndIndex);
console.log(onlyLastAnd);
```

Comment: Try explaining your answer