# converting object to int type in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
Index                                                      object
Month Id                                                   int64
Customer - ID                                              object
Billed Customer - Name                                     object
Status - -Customer                                         object
Original Contract Id  -                                    object
NIcode - NI Code                                           int64
Total Bytes                                                object
dtype: object
```

I am trying to make a pivot table with values as 'Total Bytes' and I am converting the column 'Total Bytes' to int but getting error

```
df['Total Bytes']=pd.to_numeric(df['Total Bytes'])
```

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,429,155,997.00'
```

Some of the values in 'Total Bytes' are:

```
9,374.00
15,131.00
5,078,065.00
6,160.00
193.096.00
```

Please help out.

Comment: replace the comma with blank and then try..

Comment: where exactly to remove comma from? I have close to 25,000 rows that I want to work on

Comment: from the entire series , `df['Total Bytes'].str.replace(',','')` but you would also have to deal with values like `193.096.00` for which you need some logic what you want to do with them

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694930/remove-all-occurrences-except-last) would be helpful in such cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df['Total Bytes'] = df['Total Bytes'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',',''))
df['Total Bytes'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Bytes'])
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much friends! really appreciate it!

Comment: but I also am getting this - 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.' Can i ignore that?

Comment: You can ignore this warning for your particular use case.

Comment: Use ```str``` methods to replace, not ```apply```.