# JavaScript regular expression to remove comma in number comma number

Tags: javascript

```
"12,56,7abc,fgh" ===> "12567abc,fgh"
"1,245abc,1a" ===> "1245abc,1a"
"1,2,3,4,5abc" ===> "12345abc"
```

How to remove comma in `(number),(number)` format?

For the test

```
const array = ["12,56,7abc,fgh", "1,245abc,1a", "1,2,3,4,5abc"]
const answer = ["12567abc,fgh", "1245abc,1a", "12345abc"]

function formatter(string){
   // here
   return // string.replace('', '') ??
}

array.map((el, i) => { 
   const formatted = formatter(el) 
   if(answer[i] === formatted){
      console.log('Success. formatted: ', formatted)
   } else {
     console.log('Failed. formatted: ', formatted)
   }
})
```

Comment: `.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g,'$1$2')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all occurrences except last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694930/remove-all-occurrences-except-last)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks but not working to last string

Comment: Fine. `.replace(/(\d),(?=\d)/g,'$1')`

Comment: What is the logic for `"12345abc"` result? How exactly is it different from `"12567abc,fgh"?`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Wow!!! It's working. Is it okay for just a comment ? if you write it as answer I will take it.

Comment: @PM77-1 Only Number,Number to NumberNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.replace(/(?<=\d),(?=\d)/g, '')
```

(?<=\d): lookbehind - a digit

(?=\d) : lookahead - a digit